# How to disable underlining of highlighted matching brackets?

Tags: faces, colors, balanced-parentheses

I want to have no underlining on highlighted matching brackets. I've done the following to achieve that:

```
M-x customize-face
show-paren-match
```

And there I deactivated the underlining of matching parenthesis. However, when I restart emacs the underlining in that same setting is checked again. It seems I can't turn it off forever by changing it this way.

How do I turn it off?

If you look at this screenshot, you can see some teal underlining below the brackets:

[image]

It's also in other files, not only on that settings buffer. In my init file I already have these lines:

```
 '(cursor ((t (:background "gold" :foreground "#151718"))))
 '(show-paren-match ((t (:background "yellow green" :foreground "black"))))
 '(show-paren-mismatch ((t (:underline (:color "#CE4045" :style wave))))))
```

So I do want a red wave below brackets, which have no counterpart, but none on the matching ones.

Comment: I don't understand. I want to change the colors of them, so I need to fiddle with the configuration for that, be it in the buffer for their settings or in my init file. I do not want to disable the highlighting completely. Merely the underlining is annoying me. How can disabling help with that?

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution that seems to work:

[image]

Instead of unchecking the attribute `underline`, it seems, that it needs to be checked, but set to `Off`. I also changed other settings for the brackets, which you can see in the screenshot.

Comment: It should not be necessary to do that. It should be sufficient to uncheck `Underline`. Face definitions with that attibute unchecked do not have underlines, normally. Consider filing a bug report: `M-x report-emacs-bug`.